# iOS GoogleMaps StreetView URL Scheme with Heading and Pitch

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-street-view, google-maps-urls

Is there any way to open google maps app in streetview mode with desired heading and pitch?

There is example in [Google Maps URL Scheme for iOS Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme) with latitude, longitude and zoom, but there is nothing written about pitch and heading. It does not works when i try to embed parameters in URL like this **&pitch=
&heading=**

There must be some way how to achieve this, because when i open street view in Safari browser and Safari offers me deeplink to Google Maps app it opens with exactly same heading and pitch like in Safari

I know that there are other options like embed google maps in app or open map URL in safari, but i need to open it in google maps app.

Comment: Pitch is called viewing angle and heading is called bearing in Google's documentation. Try searching for those and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

In 2017 Google launched [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#universal-cross-platform-syntax) which is currently the recommended cross-platform syntax to open Google Maps app both in iOS and Android devices.

The Google Maps URLs has a [street view](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#street-view-action) mode and parameters `heading`, `pitch` and `fov` are supported.

So, you can use the new cross-platform syntax instead of the Google Maps URL scheme for iOS.

Example, from the official documentation

`https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=pano&viewpoint=48.857832,2.295226&heading=-45&pitch=38&fov=80`

I hope this helps!